# Bearings and distances

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Two ships leave port at the same time. One travels at $5$ km/h on a bearing of $46$ degrees. The other travels at $9$ km/h on a bearing of $127$ degrees. How far apart are the ships after $2$ hours?

Answer (score 1):

So, this will make a triangle, with one point being the port, and the other two points being the points where both ships are after 2 hours.

So, the angle between the two ships is $127-46=81$ degrees apart.

Also, one ship is $10$ km out $(5km/h*2h)$ and the other is is $18$ km out $(9km/h*2h)$

So, we have a triangle with an angle of $81$ degrees, and one side is $10$km, and the other is $18$km. How can we find the other side? Law of cosines. the law of cosines is:

$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C$$

We know that $a=10$ and $b=18$ (or we can switch those two, it doesn't really matter) and that C=$81$ degrees. Can you solve what the distance between them is from here?